# Swift / Parse: Checking to make sure the data loaded

Tags: ios, ipad, swift, parse-platform

Got an app written in Swift that creates a PFObject, saves it and then goes to another view controller. At that view controller, the data is read from Parse.com and displayed on the page. In the simulator and on my iPad Air 2, the app runs fine. On older iPads, however, it crashes at the new view controller. I think it's a simple matter of trying to show the data before it's loaded. I've put in a delay that stops the crash, but I'd like a more elegant solution.

I'd like to be able to check to see if the data is loaded (that's easy - if data != nil) but if it is nil, how do I get it to sit and wait for it to load? Any suggestions?

I'm a noob so feel free to talk slowly... ;)

Thanks!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29790100/2303865

Comment: Don't forget to vote it up if it solves your problem :)

Comment: @Leonardo Savio Dabus that did the trick. Thank you very much!